# Android fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) runOnUiThread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to make a simple Android animation of dog paw walking on the screen. I am doing that by making one XML screen with 6 dog paws, and setting visibility each of them in the code. The code is organized in a way that there is on UI thread that changes visibility on every 500ms. After 10 cycles, I try to start a new Activity. At this point I get exception and my app restarts. What could be a problem ? There is the snippet of my code:

```
Thread UI_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    //Thread.sleep(300);

                    while (cnt < 11) {


                     Thread.sleep(500);



                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                             if (cnt == 10) {
                                 // Start second screen
                                 Img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Img3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Img5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Img6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Intent IntroScreen2Act = new Intent(IntroScreen1.this, IntroScreen2.class);
                                 startActivity(IntroScreen2Act);

                             }

                            switch (cnt) {
                            case 0:
                                Img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                Img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                Img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                Img5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 5:
                                Img6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                            }

                        }
                    });
                     cnt ++;
                     Log.d("Thread", "Cycle " + Integer.toString(cnt));
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    });


    UI_thread.start();
```

LogCat:

```
07-30 14:19:34.082: E/dalvikvm-heap(22071): Out of memory on a 44049616-byte allocation. 07-30 14:19:34.102: A/libc(22071): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 22071
```

Comment: Please post your logcat data where we can see exception occurring.

Comment: From the logcat error I can say that your app is consuming to much memory. Its throwing out of memory error. Reduce your memory consumption so that this Out Of Memory error should not arise

Comment: I cannot find what is actually consuming the memory. All images are 40KB.

Comment: Compressed image size does not matter, what matters is the actual size (dimensions) of these images. Read this : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: You can use Timer class instead of simple thread which will allow you to skip Sleep method and the loop. It will start and run continuously for the time you have specified. Check the Timer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call runOnUiThread(), the code isn't run immediately. It's just added as a request on the message queue of the display thread. So it will be executed "a little later", where the OS decides when "a little later" is.

The big problem is you're starting a background thread that uses runOnUiThread() to access the main thread which is fine, but once startActivity() is called the current UI thread is being destroyed. But

1. setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) is being queued/called
2. the current UI thread is being "deleted"/"taken off the stack" because startActivity() is called
3. you aren't calling finish() or returning to explicitly tell the system to end the activity NOW so the rest of the run() method is still being executed. This means the UI thread may still be busy and startActivity() will take effect "a little later".

My guess is the combination of those 3 items above is causing the UI thread to be accessed after the OS has started cleaning it up, hence the segfault i.e. a view is being referenced too late